# How to call module_init macro?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a simple char device driver. The function which we pass to module_init() is called at the time of module installation.

When we insert the module using insmod command the function passes to module_init() is gets called.

Is there any other method to call this module_init() function.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about using something else than `insmod`, then no: `insmod` is the only way I know to initialize your module.

Otherwise, this `module_init` thing is a macro and isn't really a function call (you cannot call a function from global scope in C). It expands to some predefined "module constructor" that calls your initializing function, depending on if you're compiling as a dynamic module or as an object built into the kernel. Its role is to avoid having to `#ifdef` a lot when developing a module and making the development process easier (see [this](http://people.netfilter.org/rusty/unreliable-guides/kernel-hacking/routines-init-again.html)).

So if, for some reason (but I discourage you doing this), you want to call your initializing function from your module code, then just call it directly. For example:

```c
static void some_other_function(void) {
    // ...
    initialize();
    // ...
}

static int initialize(void) {
    // your initialization code
}

module_init(initialize);
```

**Edit**: removed `__init` following Eugene's comment.

However, I recommend only the `module_init` expansion calls your initialization function and that other *common* code be in a separate function:

```c
static void some_other_function(void) {
    // ...
    something_that_might_get_called_afterwards_also();
    // ...
}

static int __init initialize(void) {
    // your initialization code (done only once)
    something_that_might_get_called_afterwards_also();
    // some other one-time code
}

module_init(initialize);
```

Comment: If one is going to call `initialize()` from this example directly after the module has completed its initialization, I suppose, it is better not to mark it with `__init`. The functions marked this way (as well as the data marked with `__init_data`) are unloaded from memory by the loader after the module's initializition finishes. So calling them after that would result in a kernel oops. If they are not marked with `__init`, they will remain in memory and can be called. But I agree with @eepp, it is better not to do so and rather use a separate function.